# Why controller called twice, when state changes?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is my app.js

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'satellizer'])
     .constant('API_URL', 'http://localhost/angular/public/api/v1/')
     .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $authProvider) {
         $authProvider.loginUrl = 'angular/public/api/authenticate';
         $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/auth');
         $stateProvider
             .state('auth', {
                 url: '/auth',
                 templateUrl: 'app/view/login.html',
                 controller: 'AuthController as auth'
             })
             .state('dashboard', {
                 url: '/dashboard',
                 templateUrl: 'app/view/dashboard.tmpl.html',
                 params: {
                     model: ''
                 }
             })
             .state('dashboard.employees', {
                 templateUrl: 'app/view/employee.tmpl.html',
                 controller: 'employeesController',

             }).state('dashboard.test', {

                 templateUrl: 'app/view/edit.tmpl.html',
                 controller: 'employeesController',

             })
     });
```

When I click `ui-sref="dashboard.employees"` controller calls twice.

[calls twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCoQf.png)

This is my controller which I want to use for all views. I developed cms on laravel and angular. I can't create a new controller for every table entity.

```
 angular.module('app')
    .controller('employeesController', function($scope, $http, API_URL,$stateParams) {
        //retrieve employees listing from API
        $scope.employees = '';


    $http.get(API_URL +  $stateParams.model)
        .success(function(response) {

            $scope.employees = response;
        });
    //show modal form
    $scope.toggle = function(modalstate, id) {
        $scope.modalstate = modalstate;

        switch (modalstate) {
            case 'add':
                $scope.form_title = "Add New Employee";
                break;
            case 'edit':
                $scope.form_title = "Employee Detail";
                $scope.id = id;
                $http.get(API_URL + $stateParams.model+'/' + id)
                    .success(function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        $scope.employee = response;
                    });
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }

    //save new record / update existing record
    $scope.save = function(modalstate, id) {
        var url = API_URL + "employees";

        //append employee id to the URL if the form is in edit mode
        if (modalstate === 'edit') {
            url += "/" + id;
        }
        console.log('saved');
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: $.param($scope.employee),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        }).success(function(response) {
            var index = _.findIndex($scope.employees, function(b) {
                return b.id == $scope.employee.id;
            });
              console.log(index);
            if (index != -1) {
                $scope.employees[index] = $scope.employee;
            } else {

              console.log($scope.employee);
                $scope.employee.id = response;
                $scope.employees.push($scope.employee);
                console.log($scope.employees);
            }
            $('#myModal').modal('toggle');

        }).error(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            alert('This is embarassing. An error has occured. Please check the log for details');
        });
    }

    //delete record
    $scope.confirmDelete = function(employee) {
        var isConfirmDelete = confirm('Are you sure you want this record?');
        if (isConfirmDelete) {
            $http({
                method: 'DELETE',
                url: API_URL + 'employees/' + employee.id
            }).
            success(function(data) {
                _.remove($scope.employees, function(n) {
                    return n.id == employee.id;
                });
                console.log(data);
            }).
            error(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                alert('Unable to delete');
            });
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Where is my mistake? How can I fix that?

Comment: are you talking about while loading??

Comment: no, when i move between states

Comment: Your image doesn't show that your controller is called twice, but that an api call is made from your controller twice. Please include your controller code.

Comment: You are using same controller for both states. So, its normal, angular will reinitialize the controller. So, either use a parent child relationship or make 2 separate controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kindly check, if you are called the controller in your `employee.tmpl.html` page, like `ng-controller="employeesController"`

Please **remove** it, if you call the `ng-controller` in your `html`

Comment: If you using `ng-controller="employeesController"` in anywhere, please just remove it